# PHP Generating Post Data

Tags: php, html, forms, post, header

So I have a registration page where the user registers with all his/her information and then when they click submit, I have the action of the form set as `action="Scripts/Insert.php`.

What insert does is simply take all the inputted information and insert it into my database. After that, I need to redirect them to another site where they can pay. But I need to post some data to the following site. For security reasons I **HAVE** to send it through POST and not session. I tried inserting the required information into the post array inside or `Insert.php` but the post array got cleared when I redirected. So Insert looks something like this:

```
$gen = new Generator();
$_POST["SITEID"] = 3;

//Validation Key Generator
$_POST["TransactionID"] = $gen->keygen(10);
$_POST["Amount"] = 500;
$salt = "somelongstring";
$_POST["VALIDATION_KEY"] = base64_encode(md5($posting_valKey+$_POST["EXT_TRANS_ID"]+$_POST["AMT"]));

//Use PDO to insert previous page form information into the database

header("Location: www.paymentsite.com/index.jsp");
```

But like I said the post gets erased so nothing gets sent to the site. So how do I generate some post data here and send it to the site? I was thinking of a possible solution being to echo a html form with hidden fields that has these values but then there were two problems with that:

1. How to i use the variables in the input values? Could I do this:

   ```
   echo "<input type='hidden' value="$salt" name='salt'>"
   ```
2. And then how do I submit the form?

If my solutions sucks please let me know any other way(s) of posting from a php to another website. Thanks.

Comment: Where you need to start [is with learning about curl](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+post+with+curl&submit=search)  Writing into `$_POST` won't persist beyond the current script execution.

Comment: Yeah, that's not how $_POST works. Think of it as **read-only**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Do you need to physically push the user to another site or just send the form info there?

If you need to post to the outside site you can just use a hidden field to pass the necessary info. You would change your action parameter to the receiving site www.paymentsite.com/index.jsp

You'd think the payment site would have a basic integration tutorial for you though. If they don't they're probably not worth using.

Just to clarify, the user sends the info of form and hidden fields when they click the submit button. If you make the action point to the receiving site it would take them there automatically. But that might be obvious, so I question the actual needs of your site. Do you post to yourself first to create a transaction record, reference or something needed by the receiving site? So you know what account to credit the payment to? Can this be done before the page loads?

I guess I just don't know why you post to yourself first. If you update your question with that and perhaps the payment processor you're posting to we might be able to refine the answer

Comment: "After that, I need to redirect them to another site where they can pay"

Comment: @Sam Dufel: My site is always at his service for that purpose >:)

Comment: @raidenance - I've read over your comment many times... what do you mean?

Comment: That would make sense if his site lead anywhere. If anything it got me to click the link

Comment: @KaiQing: that was just a joke, for crying our loud :)  Sorry it made you click on my non-existent URL. All in good fun..

Answer (score 0):

You have different possibilities, two of them are Curl and Pecl.

More information: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php